# Roboto font issue in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, roboto

I'm having the issue in chrome with Roboto font family.

This works fine in firefox but chrome is not giving **letter spacing** between `F` and `L` as you can see in pictures.

---

**In chrome :**
[image]

---

**In firefox :**
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called a [typographic ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). You can stop Chrome from displaying it, like this:

```
h1 {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-variant-ligatures: none;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work throughout all webkit browsers. Safari will show the ligature anyway.

**Read more**

- [MDN: "font-variant-ligatures"](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/4bocbjru/)

Comment: Thank you so much @insertusernamehere Got one new thing to learn. :)